# jenkins startip error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 130 in LocalVariableTypeTable has bad constant type in class file hudson/model/Items

Tags: jenkins, hudson, java.lang.class

jenkins suddenly reported an error,The specific error is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 130 in LocalVariableTypeTable has bad constant type in class file hudson/model/Items
    at hudson.model.ItemGroup.allItems(ItemGroup.java:148)
    at hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver$Migrator.onLoaded(ArtifactArchiver.java:386)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:1040)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:261)
```

and journalctl log error as follows:

```
WARNING        jenkins.model.Jenkins$5#runTask: Loading plugin Maven Integration plugin v3.23 (maven-plugin) failed perhaps due to plugin dependency
 Also:   java.io.IOException: CRC error while extracting entry from JAR file
                 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getBytes(URLClassPath.java:886)
                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 130 in LocalVariableTypeTable has bad constant type in class file hudson/model/Items
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
         at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:594)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:567)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:502)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
         at hudson.util.MaskingClassLoader.loadClass(MaskingClassLoader.java:80)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
         at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.start(PluginImpl.java:44)
         at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.startPlugin(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:417)
         at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:406)
 Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize
         at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:409)
         at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:556)
         at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
         at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
         at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1164)
         at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
         at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
         at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 2024-02-27 11:24:01.516+0000 [id=44]        WARNING        hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz#scout: Failed to scout jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty$DescriptorImpl
 Also:   java.io.IOException: CRC error while extracting entry from JAR file
                 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getBytes(URLClassPath.java:886)
                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 130 in LocalVariableTypeTable has bad constant type in class file hudson/model/Items
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
         at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:594)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:567)
         at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:502)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

I tried to start jenkins using java11 but failed,How do I troubleshoot the problem or do anything to get Jenkins back to normal,please help me! thanks!